# Need to Remove Credit Card option in one store

Tags: magento, payment

Need to Remove Credit Card option in one store - Magento 1.7.0.2. This is a multisite and needs to be disabled. Could anyone help in this?
I tried in :

> **System-> Configuration-> Sales-> Payment Methods**

I could not see any disabled option. Do we have any methods to disable from back end?

Comment: Solution suggested here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36883/how-to-restrict-payment-methods-by-store

Comment: Am using Ogone as payment method and the credit card option comes from that so I need to configure in that. could you anyone help me in this